# c# access custom linked list object's element

Tags: c#, linked-list

I have created custom linked list in c#.

LinkedList.cs:

```
class LinkedList
{
    private Node Start;//Mazgas pr
    private Node End;//Mazgas pb
    private Node Current;// Mazas d saraso sasajai

    public LinkedList()
    {
        this.Start = null;
        this.End = null;
        this.Current = null;
    }

    public Object Get(int index)
    {
        for( Node curr = Start; curr != null; curr = curr.Next)
        {   
            if( curr.Index == index )
                return curr.Data;
        }
        return null;
    }

    public void PrintData()
    {
        for (Node curr = Start; curr != null; curr = curr.Next)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", curr.Index, curr.Data);
        }
    }

    public int Count()
    {
        int i = 0;
        for( Node curr = Start; curr != null; curr = curr.Next, i++);
        return i;
    }

    public void Add(Object data)
    {
        Node current = new Node(data, null);
        if (Start != null)
        {
            End.Next = current;
            End.Next.Index = End.Index + 1;
            End = current;
        }
        else
        {
            Start = current;
            End = current;
            End.Index = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Node.cs:

```
class Node
{
    public Object Data { get; set; }
    public Node Next { get; set; }
    public int Index { get; set; }

    public Node() { }

    public Node(Object data, Node next )
    {
        Data = data;
        Next = next;
    }

    public override string ToString ()
    {
        return string.Format ("Data: {0}", Data);
    }
}
```

and Part.cs

```
class Part
{
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public double Price { get; set; }

    public Part(string code, string name, double price)
    {
        Code = code;
        Name = name;
        Price = price;
    }

    public Part() { }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("{0} {1}", Name, Code);
    }
}
```

Problem is, when i create list `LinkedList parts = new LinkedList()`
and add objects to it `parts.Add(new Part("code", "name", 10));` **i can't access Part object variables**. I need to do this:

```
for( int i=0; i<parts.Count(); i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0}", (Part)Parts.Get(i).Name);
}
```

but it gives me error:

> Error CS1061: Type 'object' does not contain a definition for 'Name'
>   and no extension method 'Name' of type 'object' could be found. Are
>   you missing an assembly reference? (CS1061)

EDITED: I need this linked list to be flexible for any type of object.

Comment: You could add additional brackets around the **Part** cast like; `Console.WriteLine("{0}", ((Part)parts.Get(i)).Name);`

Comment: `(Part)Parts.Get(i).Name` is equivalent to `(Part)(Parts.Get(i).Name)` and since return value of your `Get(i)` is of type `object` and object doesn't have `Name` property, you received the exception.

Comment: You're probably looking for [generics](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/512aeb7t.aspx).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`(Part)Parts.Get(i).Name` is equivalent to `(Part)(Parts.Get(i).Name)` and since return value of your `Get(i)` is of type `object` and object doesn't have `Name` property, you received the exception.

You can correct it this way:

```
((Part)Parts.Get(i)).Name
```

**Note:**

- I suppose it's just for learning purpose.
- If all items of the list are of the same type, you can make your [`Generic`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/512aeb7t.aspx) classes. Having a generic `Node<T>` and `LinkedList<T>` class you can change the input parameters and return values to `T` instead of `object`.
- In a real application, you can use [`LinkedList<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/he2s3bh7(v=vs.110).aspx) or other generic data structures available.

Comment: You are welcome. Consider reading [Generics (C# Programming Guide)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/512aeb7t.aspx).